# Как оптимально работать с FS для записи журнала транзакций и быть уверенным, что данные записаны на диск, без частого вызова метода fs.Flush(true) C#

Tags: c#, filestream, транзакции

Всем здравствуйте!

**============ UPDATE =============**

**Решил обновить описание, т.к. оно было написано крайне криво, и обсуждение ушло не в ту сторону**

**upd:** В терминалогии СУБД, как оказалось, это называется "Протокол ведения журнала с опережением записи (WAL)"

**Есть 2 очереди:**

```
// 1. Очередь записи бинарных данных в файл (журнал)
ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> Queue1;
```

```
// 2. Очередь последующей обработки данных
ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> Queue2;
```

Данные в очередь (1) записи попадают из разных потоков, данные туда могут попадать 1 раз в день, а могут миллион за одну секунду, причем размер сообщения может быть от 20 байт до 4 гигабайт.

Первую (1) очередь обрабатывает отдельный поток, при появлении данных он начинает последовательно пытаться записать данные в файл. Стрим всегда открыт, даже если нет данных. Т.е. ситуация, при которой после каждого записанного сообщения файл закрывается не рассматривается в принципе.

После достижения определенного размера файл закрывается, затем открывается новый файл для записи и работа продолжается.

```
// Схематичный код потока обработки 1 очереди 
while (true)
{
    // Если в очереди есть сообщения, считываем первое (без извлечения)
    if (Queue1.TryPeek(out byte[] message))
    {
        // Увеличиваем переменную с порядковым номером сообщения и присваиваем индекс сообщению (~условно)
        message.Index = ++index;
        // Если стрима для записи нет, создаем его, в качестве имени используем индекс текущего сообщения
        if (fs == null) fs = new FileStream($"{TLOG_PATH}{index}.log", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

        // Записываем сообщение в стрим (message в данном случае это byte[])
        fs.Write(message);

        // Перекидываем сообщение в очередь 2, однако это не значит что поток обрабатывающий очередь 2 может этими данными уже пользоваться, пока гарантий записи на диск нет!!!
        Queue2.Enqueue(message);
        // Извлекаем обработанное сообщение
        Queue1.TryDequeue(out _);

        // Если в очереди 1 больше нет данных, вызываем метод принудительной очистки буферов с ожиданием выполнения
        if (Queue1.Count == 0)
        {
            // Ждем пока FS гарантировано запишет данные на диск
            fs.Flush(true);
            // Устанавливаем индекс гарантированно записанного сообщения
            writedIndexMessage = index;
        }

        // Если размер файла журнала больше максимального закрываем файл
        if (fs.Length >= MAX_FS_LEN)
        {
            // Флушим
            fs.Flush(true);
            // Закрываем поток
            fs.Close();
            // Вызываем деструктор 
            fs.Dispose();
            // Освобождаем переменную
            fs = null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Схематичный код потока обработки 2й очереди
while (true)
{
    // Если в очереди есть транзакции, считываем первый (без извлечения)
    // и сверяем значение индекса сообщения с индексом сообщения гарантированно записанным на диск 1м потоком
    if (Queue2.TryPeek(out byte[] message) && message.Index <= writedIndex)
    {
        // ~~~~ Делаем что-то с данными ~~~~
        AnyDo(message);
        // Убираем успешно обработанное сообщение из очереди 2
        Queue2.TryDequeue(out _);
    }
}
```

(!!!) Вопросы:

// PS. Пожалуйста, имейте ввиду что код схематичный, тут нету оптимизаций работы с потоками (Thread) и т.п. Я понимаю что эти два потока в текущем примере полностью будут занимать 2 ядра.

1. Есть ли какой-то простой/штатный механиз (в C# .net core 3.1+), используя который мы гарантировано можем знать, что данные физически записались на блин диска, без использования вызова метода fs.Flush(true), и данный механизм гарантировал бы, что при внезапном выключении питания, и последующей загрузке мы эти данные можем (!) гарантировано прочитать из файла. (разумеется если с физическим диском все в порядке), т.е. все блоки данных гарантировано записались, ссылки на блоки гарантировано записались в файловой системе, и данные точно можно будет прочитать.
2. Какие вы видите варианты оптимизации данного алгоритма, учитывая, что запись будет вестись на HDD диск, таким образом что-бы максимально снизить нагрузку на диск (что-бы голова не ходила туда сюда, например заранее выделять под файл определенный размер на диске), и при этом максимально сократить задержки между обработкой сообщения в 1й очереди и 2й очереди. Например:

   - Возможно при наличии большой очереди каждые 100 миллисекунд делать принудительную запись на диск (таким образом, ориентировочная задержка между обработкой сообщений будет +100 мс при большой очереди)
   - Возможно считать размер записанных данных и размер кластера (который программа допустим каким-то образом будет знать) и предполагать что в кэше диска блок сформирован и записан на диск. Но тут очень спорный момент.
   - В плане подготовки файла возможно заранее готовить файлы по 100 мегабайт, в свободное время записывать туда нули (если это не делает файловая система сама) и в дальнейшем диску будет проще работать с файлом т.к. не нужно будет мотать головой для записи данных блоков в заголовок файла.
3. Возможно ли разное поведение при записи в файл на разных файловых системах  ntfs/ext3/ext4/... и разных операционных системах? Либо .NET Core 3.1+ гарантирует что после вызова метода fs.Flush(true), данные гарантировано записались на физический диск (энергонезависисый кэш).
4. Требуется ли какая-то дополнительная оптимизация кода если предусматривается использование аппаратных рейдов с энергонезависимым кэшем (кэш с батарейкой), и разумеется мы заранее не знаем есть ли он, например при использовании СХД и крутясь на виртуалке. (Предполагаю что не требуется, но все же задам вопрос, вдруг есть подводные камни)

На 100% уверен, что все кто разрабатывал базы данных сталкивался с данной проблемой, т.к. запись данных в таблицы и построение индексов происходит ТОЛЬКО после записи транзакции (если БД поддерживает транзакции И эта функция не отключена специально)

**upd:** В терминалогии СУБД, как оказалось, это называется "Протокол ведения журнала с опережением записи (WAL)"

**upd:** По мере получения конкретных данных и опыта, обязуюсь представить оптимальный код на C#, в отдельном сообщении. Возможно кому-то сэкономит массу времени. С последующим вылизыванием, если у кого-то будут объективные поправки.

**Буду рад и ссылкам на любой касающийся этой темы материал (на любом языке) и личным комментариям. Заранее Огромное Спасибо.**

Comment: Несколько раз перечитал, надеюсь понял :-) А варианты расположения файловой системы не на диске рассматриваются? Взять tmpfs и замонтировать её в память?

Comment: Нет, транзакции (и их хранение) нужны для того, что-бы в случае аварийной перезагрузки системы, система могла восстановить целостность базы данных. В случае использования tmpfs при сбое питания, данные транзакций пропадут.
Данные в базу данных записываются по каждому отдельному объекту а не транзакцией целиком.

Comment: С практической точки зрения лучше взять готовую embedded БД с поддержкой диска (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net например) и ее использовать. Самому это правильно реализовать - задача непростая.

Comment: Вопрос не в том, что нужно использовать возможности MySQL! 
Технология разработана, оно уже работает в продакшне, но не оптимально, код описанный выше это крайне упрощенный пример, журнал транзакций описанный выше гораздо сложнее и используется для много чего еще в конвейере обработки транзакции (репликация и т.п.), плюс ко всему используемая СУБД это не какая-то конкретная СУБД, может быть любая удовлетворяющая определенным требованиям. Вопрос ТОЛЬКО в том, как оптимизировать работу с файлом при потоковой записи, и как узнать о гарантированной записи в минимальные сроки.

Comment: Никто не спорит что задача не простая, сама технология пилится уже не один год. Вообще журнал транзакций нужен только для подстраховки, для того что-бы при следующем старте программы распределенная система перешла в работоспособное состояние, правильно дозаписались транзакции в СУБД (одну или несколько при мультиплексировании), синхронизировались журналы транзакций между собой (мультиплексирование), реплицировались данные между узлами и т.п. и т.д. Это нужно для гарантированной отказоустойчивости.

Comment: В случае рейда с батарейкой способа нет. Посмотрите https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234656/information-about-using-disk-drive-caches-with-sql-server-that-every-d , там детально расписано как работает write ahead log в sql server - он решает ту же проблему

Comment: Павел, спасибо! Вот уже нашли концы... Буду изучать

Answer (score 3):

Решение, которое обычно используется в СУБД - это Write Ahead Log, запись в лог до того, как операция (сообщение) будет помечено как обработанное. В вашем случае - это запись в лог до вызова `TryDequeue`

[SQL Server использует при этом флаг FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234656/information-about-using-disk-drive-caches-with-sql-server-that-every-d), в случае C# - это [флаг `FileOptions.WriteThrough`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileoptions?view=net-5.0).

`FileOptions.WriteThrough` работает и на Windows и [на Unix](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/abc525d0c2a5b0be09e4d7e4c1e67571afb77c80/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/FileStream.Unix.cs#L194), так что никаких дополнительных хаков под разные платформы не требуется.

В случае рейда с батарейкой обеспечить реальную запись на диск не получится, придется полагаться на надежность контроллера и батарейки.

Answer (score 1):

Я хоть не в теме, но интересно, попробую чуть-чуть вникнуть и на что-то ответить.
Вообще всю информацию для ответа я надеюсь добыть по ссылке https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/find/master введя фразу *filestream*.

Вы задали очень много вопросов в одном, это нарушает правила и ставит в затруднённое положение отвечающего. Ну да ладно, поехали..

> Что происходит после выполнения функции fs.Flush(false)

> Что происходит после выполнения функции fs.Flush(true)

```
public virtual void Flush(bool flushToDisk)
{
    if (IsClosed) throw Error.GetFileNotOpen();

    FlushInternalBuffer();

    if (flushToDisk && CanWrite)
    {
        FlushOSBuffer();
    }
}
```

Первое очищает буфер в памяти приложения, второе вдобавок вызывает специальную очистку буфера ОС. Это очистка производиться средствами самой ОС и, что вполне объяснимо, реализация зависит от собственно типа ОС.

UNIX

```
if (Interop.Sys.FSync(_fileHandle) < 0) 
{
   //обработка ошибок
}
```

WINDOWS

```
if (!Interop.Kernel32.FlushFileBuffers(_fileHandle))
{
   //обработка ошибок
}
```

Что примечательно асинхронные версии `FlushAsync` лишены такой функциональности. Так же не увидел я очистки буфера ОС и в `Dispose()`.

> Что происходит после выполнения команды fs.Write(anydata) под капотом

Зависит от режима. Есть асинхронный и синхронный. Асинхронный я изучу когда-нибудь потом. А в синхронном происходит следующее. Вызывается `private void WriteSpan(ReadOnlySpan<byte> source)` он  собственно отвечает за накопление данных в буфере, и при переполнениях по сути проводит аналогичную процедуру `Flush(false)`, в результате которой в конечном итоге вызывается в Windows `Interop.Kernel32.WriteFile()`, а вот в UNIX, такая конструкция

```
fixed (byte* bufPtr = &MemoryMarshal.GetReference(source))
{
    int offset = 0;
    int count = source.Length;
    while (count > 0)
    {
        int bytesWritten = CheckFileCall(Interop.Sys.Write(_fileHandle, bufPtr + offset, count));
        _filePosition += bytesWritten;
        offset += bytesWritten;
        count -= bytesWritten;
    }
}
```

> возможно лучшая практика котролировать время между командами fs.FLUSH и например выполнять их каждые 100 мс.

Возможно. Есть смысл провести тесты производительности